# How to extract particular part of a string?

Tags: android

I have a Link which never changes. The only thing which changes is the file name (in bold). so how do I get the file name from this link? I want to display this in a textview or toast-

`http://apkins.aptoide.com/`**aptoide-8.1.0.1.apk**`?=x`

Answer (score 1):

```
String given = "http://apkins.aptoide.com/aptoide-8.1.0.1.apk?=x";
String extractedAppName = given.substring(given.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, given.lastIndexOf("?"));
```

This should work. It takes the position of the `/` before the name and then the position of the `?`. It takes the string (substring) between those two characters. Just give it a try and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

You can also try `URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null)`

**Edit 1**

```
String url = "any url"
```

Comment: was busy typing mine. didn't see yours. sorry and I don't have enough reps to comment

Comment: URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null) sounds interesting

Comment: how do I get the result?

Comment: like this:

String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null);

Comment: and you can use this:

String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, "fileExtension"); 

if you want to specify the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex-less solution:

```
public static String getFileName(String link) {
     int endIndex = link.lastIndexOf('?');
     return link.substring(26, endIndex);
 }
```

It's pretty simple. It first gets where the file name ends i.e. the position of the last "?". Then it "cuts out" a new string from the link starting from the 27th character to the end of the file name.

Comment: Same as my answer.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Yours won't work if the file name contains a "?" because you used `indexOf` instead of `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: This may fail because as I mentioned my link keeps changing, the same applies on the length and number of characters

Comment: @badmom but as you mentioned in your question, the first part is constant so the file name always starts at index 26. The last part also doesn't change so the last question mark marks the end of the file name. Can you give me an example that this does not work?